# Selenium Webdriver unable to click the sub menu item

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am able to traverse through the menu items, but the final element is not clicked by WebDriver.

My code snippet:

```java
WebElement hover0 = driver.findElement(By.id("td_Menu_0"));
WebElement hover = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='role6_Maintain']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
action.moveToElement(hover0).moveToElement(hover);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#menuClickable_0_6_0_0")))
      .click().build().perform();
```

The final `WebElement` HTML:

```html
<td onkeydown="return menuClickableOperation(this,event);" 
    onclick="javascript:deleteGrpWindowNode('menu_Maintain',0,'br_w_BusissPartner','BRGUI','Business Partner','','','HJHF');"
    onmouseout="menuDeSelect(this);" onmouseover="menuSelect(this)" 
    onmousemove="DisplayIFrame();" tabindex="11" id="menuClickable_0_6_0_0" 
    class="menuNormal2">
  <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" style="">
          <p title="Business Partner" class="MenuTxt">Business Partner</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
action.moveToElement(hover0).build().perform();
action.moveToElement(hover).build().perform();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#menuClickable_0_6_0_0")));//Waiting for 20 seconds for the final element to be visible.
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='menuClickable_0_6_0_0']//p[.='Business Partner']"))).click().build().perform();
```

---

Comment: the selenium is not throwing any exception but the element is not clicked and not even selected

Comment: Which one is the menu to hover at ? **"hover0" or **"hover"**

Comment: firstly hover on "hover0" which makes the element "hover" visible    and then on  doing mouse over on "hover" the element 'menuClickable_0_6_0_0' becomes visible

Comment: @VaibhavKhandelwal : Try the updated code above and please let me know.

Comment: I tried the updated code but same result I have put a wait till the final element is not visible and I got timeout after performing first two statements in your code

Comment: @VaibhavKhandelwal: Are the first two statements resulting in subsequent hover(s), i.e., the menu and it's submenu (before the final menu item)? That way it will be evident where is the problem. Also, if you can provide HTML code from the main menu to the final item, it will be more easy to sort this one out.

Comment: can u suggest a way by which I can keep hovering over till the final element is enabled

Comment: @VaibhavKhandelwal : Have added the code above for waiting 20 seconds till the final element is visible using Explicit wait.

Comment: in the code u provided when the webdriver is waiting for the element the menu block closes thus not able to click the final element .Thats y I think the webdriver should wait over the hover element I m using IE8

Comment: I don't think that's a problem. It's with Internet Explorer. IE has a history of problems related to hovering. And, to add onto that yours is IE-8. Try the code with another browser say firefox. I think it should probably work. If it works, then try the same code with IE but set "Persistent Hovering" to false.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already hovering on hover0 and hover, i am hoping the third object is available.
So why cant you perform direct click on the third object like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='menuClickable_0_6_0_0']//p[.='Business Partner']").click
```

The other way around your way is like

```
action.click(yourElement).build().perform()
```

Comment: The the third element is visible only for  a fraction of a sec and in this short time the web driver is not able to click the element